# Why does the following cause Visual Studio to encounter an exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional with three addons installed:

- Visual SVN
- CodeRush Xpress 11
- Pro Power Tools

When I start Visual Studio, select `New Project => Console Application (C#)` and then type the following:

```
for(){}
```

It crashes on me, every time. Is anybody else experiencing this or is it just me? Is this a known issue?

I'm getting a bit sick of Visual Studio crashing on me every time I create a for loop.

Thanks

Comment: It crashes at *design time* or at *compile time* or at *run time*?  Is it really crashing as soon as you even type that code?  Is there an option to debug the application when it crashes?

Comment: Yes it crashes as I am typing, I am wondering if I need to repair Visual Studio or if this is a known issue with one of my addons.

Comment: It's probably worth trying it without any add-ons and then with one add-on at a time.  To be honest, I've never written that exact line of code before.  It could be that one of the add-ons is trying to intelligently determine something about that loop as you type, and it can't because it's an infinite contentless loop.

Comment: Try running VS with logging enabled (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx).  This will generate an `xml` log file that could provide you with more info about what is causing the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue with the add-ons.
Disable all 3 add-ons and then enable them one by one to find out which one causes the problem.